# What is the correct way to display HTML and CSS in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

When answering/asking a question on Stack Overflow, what is the best way to display your HTML and CSS code? I first had it like this:

> html:
>
> ```
> <div class="first-div">Some content</div>
> <div>More content</div>
> ```
>
> css:
>
> ```
> .first-div {
>   background: red;
> }
> ```

But my answer was edited to be displayed like this:

> ```
> .first-div {   background: red; }
> ```
>
> ```
> <div class="first-div">Some content</div>
> <div>More content</div>
> ```

I have also seen more posts that display it as the last example, so is the latter the better way to display it?

Comment: I don't really see what's different between the two

Comment: It is just the way it is displayed. So in the one I show which code I am displaying and the other one just shows the code, with the css first and html second. I don't know if that is the proper way to show it on SO?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your code consists of HTML and CSS, better to use a [code-snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

This way other users can not only see the code, but the result of your code running on their browser.

Other than that, the two examples you posted in this meta question are mostly equivalent. The header saying what kind of code that block has doesn't add much, but their removal can be said to be kinda arbitrary.

But [the edit that was suggested for your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56108855/revisions) was exactly what I mentioned earlier: converted the code in your post into a runnable code-snippet, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Okay cool, I definitely agree with the code snippet (will remember for the future) and as for the display method, yes, I think that is probably just better practice. I just thought there was a specific way to display it.